# Get Next piece of text after string - Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: html, parsing, dom

I want to parse the text "General" which appears after Skillset. It will always appear after Skillset. But the Skillset, Area etc. order could vary.

```
<div class="job_description">
<span class="bold">Required</span> 
<ul> 
   <li> Bachelor's </li> 
   <li> Fluent </li> 
</ul>   
Equal opportunity employer. 
<br><br>
<b> Skillset </b>: General <br>
<b> Area </b>: (all other) <br>
<b> Unit </b>: HR <br>
<b> Role </b>: Other <br>
<b> Admin </b>: No
</div>
```

Comment: is it exactly in this html code? what is the parent html element?

Comment: Why not just embed each `<b>ATTRIBUTE</b> : VALUE` in a `<div>` element. It looks however better than using `br` at the end of each line

Comment: yes, the parent html element is: <div class="jobdesc">
I can not change the html, I can only parse it.